# Sierra wireless MC7455 under Ubuntu 18.04 can not connect to internet

Tags: at-command, modem, internet-connection, dial-up, 3g-network

I was trying to connect to the internet using Sierra wireless MC7455 under Ubuntu.
At this point installed GobiNet and now can connect to the modem via picocom.
When typing:

```
**at+cops=?**
-> *0,0,"Partner",7*
**at+creg?**
-> +CREG: 0,1
**at+cgpaddr=1**
-> *1,"My static ip"*
```

When trying to connect from outside or open any URL it is not possible -> "No internet connection".
Am I missing something? Any configuration or library?

P.S.
The modem works great on windows 10 with skylight.

Comment: Did you were able to solve it I am facing same error